# perl module to detect foreign url

Tags: regex, perl, url, module, detect

I'm making a crawler and I only want to use U.S. domains. For example, I would want:

```
 http://thenorthface.com/
```

but I would not want:

```
http://uk.thenorthface.com
or
http://se.thenorthface.com/
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this or a perl module that does this? I know it could be done with regex, but I'm trying to avoid having to get together a list of all foreign domain beginnings... Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is a "us domain"?  I can think of a number of possible ways you could mean that.

Comment: A more reliable way would be to find out where the IP address is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably determine what a "US" domain is from the URL.  It's not even clear that the term "US domain" has any meaning.

For example, many US state abbreviations are also ISO-3166 country codes.  What will you do with `ar.xyz.com`.  Is that Arkansas or Argentina?  What about `ma.pdq.com`... Massachussetts or Morocco (Maroc in French)?

You may be able to link second-level domains to a country (for a headquarters at least) but hostnames and third-level domains will be impossible to classify.